how to fix the undo function for a paint app made using turtle and tkinter
i am making a paint app in python. it has functions for making shapes and drawing using click and drag.
i've been trying to implement an undo button to my app. it work fine to undo the shapes but not so well to undo the click and drag lines.
my function :
def undo ():
    if la[len(la)-1] =='s' : 
        turtle.undo()
        del(la[len(la)-1])
        while(turtle.isdown()==True) :
            turtle.undo()
        turtle.undo()
        turtle.undo()
    if la[len(la)-1]=='d' :
        turtle.undo()
        del(la[len(la)-1])
        while turtle.xcor()!=xp[len(xp)-1] and turtle.ycor()!=yp[len(yp)-1] :
            turtle.undo()
        del(xp[len(xp)-1])
        del(yp[len(yp)-1])

la is an array that memorizes whether the last action was drawing a line or a shape.
if its a shape ('s') it undoes while the pen is down ( since the shapes are made using turtle action the pen doesn't lift between those action ).
if its a line ('d') it should undo until the coords of the turtle are the same as the coords of the beginning of the line ( memorized in xp and yp ).
well sometimes it undoes more than it should and sometimes it doesn't undo at all. the thing is that most times it works perfectly so i don't know what causes the problems. most frequently it has problems when there's a shape before the line, it undoes part of the shape too. and of course if you cross the begging of the line multiple times it stops undoing but that can be fixed by counting how many times you crossed it.
edit :
minimal working program :
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle, Shape


menu = Tk()

frame=Frame(menu, bd=1, bg='#d1c7c7')
frame.grid(row=1, column=6, rowspan=26 )
canvas=Canvas(frame,width=1000, height=700)
canvas.grid(column=6,row=1, rowspan=26)

size=5

la=['n']
xp=[]
yp=[]

# turtle actions
def draw(x, y):
    turtle.ondrag(None)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.up()
    screen.update()
    turtle.ondrag(draw)
def move(x, y):
    global xp
    global yp
    global la
    xp.append(turtle.xcor())
    yp.append(turtle.ycor())
    la.append('d') 
    screen.onscreenclick(None)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    screen.onclick(move)
    screen.update()
def main():
    turtle.shape("circle")
    polygon = turtle.get_shapepoly()
    fixed_color_turtle = Shape("compound")
    fixed_color_turtle.addcomponent(polygon, "", "")
    screen.register_shape('fixed', fixed_color_turtle)
    turtle.shape("fixed")
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.pensize(5)
    turtle.turtlesize(2000,2000)
    turtle.ondrag(draw)
    screen.onscreenclick(move)
    screen.update()

def setcolor (color) :
    turtle.pencolor(color)
    turtle.fillcolor(color)




bblack = Button(
    menu,
    bg='black',
    width=10,
    command=partial(setcolor,'black')
).grid(column=1, row=2)
bred = Button(
    menu,
    bg='red',
    width=10,
    command=partial(setcolor,'red')
).grid(column=1, row=3)

bdraw = Button(
    menu,
    text='pen',
    width=10,
    command=main
).grid(column=1, row=4)

def square(x, y):
    global la
    la.append('s')
    turtle.turtlesize(1,1)
    screen.onclick(None)
    turtle.ondrag(None)
    turtle.goto(x-size*8.3, y-size*8.3)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(size*18)
        turtle.left(360 / 4)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()
    possqr()
def possqr():
    screen.onclick(square)
bsquare = Button(
    menu,
    text='square',
    width=10,
    command=possqr
).grid(column=1, row=5)
def triangle(x, y):
    global la
    la.append('s')
    turtle.turtlesize(1,1)
    screen.onclick(None)
    turtle.ondrag(None)
    turtle.goto(x-size*8.5, y-size*6)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.forward(size*18)
        turtle.left(360 / 3)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()
    postriangle()
def postriangle():
    screen.onclick(triangle)
btriangle = Button(
    menu,
    text='triangle',
    width=10,
    command=postriangle
).grid(column=1, row=6)

Label(menu, text='COLORS').grid(column=1, row=1)



def undo ():
    if la[len(la)-1] =='s' : 
        turtle.undo()
        del(la[len(la)-1])
        while(turtle.isdown()==True) :
            turtle.undo()
        turtle.undo()
        turtle.undo()
    if la[len(la)-1]=='d' :
        turtle.undo()
        del(la[len(la)-1])
        while turtle.xcor()!=xp[len(xp)-1] and turtle.ycor()!=yp[len(yp)-1] :
            turtle.undo()
        del(xp[len(xp)-1])
        del(yp[len(yp)-1])
bundo = Button(
    menu,
    text='undo',
    width=10,
    command=undo
).grid(column=2, row=1)

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.tracer(False)

pen_color = 'black'

turtle = RawTurtle(screen)
main()
mainloop()


The goal for code is a complete, runnable [mcve]. So yes, you shouldn't post too much code, but also, the code needs to be complete and runnable. So that involves stripping some unnecessary functionality out to get to the heart of the problem, while keeping the application fully operable on its own. As an aside, I suggest formatting your code so it's easily readable to others.
